# How to avoid "npm fetch GET 200" logs when invoking install in npm 5

Tags: node.js, npm

Ever since upgrade to npm 5 I get a gazillion of `npm fetch GET 200 ...` messages (see below) on my build servers despite setting `npm config set loglevel warn`. Is there a new setting for that?

```
[0m[91mnpm info[0m[91m config[0m[91m set "loglevel" "warn"
[0m[91mnpm info [0m[91mok 
[0m[91mnpm[0m[91m info it worked if it ends with ok
[0m[91mnpm info using npm@5.3.0
npm info using node@v8.3.0
[0m[91mnpm info lifecycle myapp-client@0.0.1~preinstall: myapp-client@0.0.1
[0m[91mnpm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-eslint 98ms
[0m[91mnpm http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-eslint/-/babel-eslint-7.2.3.tgz 23ms
[...]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker containers with node often set `ENV` variable `NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL` to `info` instead of the default `warn`.  You can set this `ENV` var yourself or use `npm install --logLevel warn` to override that behavior.

Comment: Looks like they reverted this behavior in Node 8.7.0 and npm 6.11.4 https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/blob/main/README.md#verbosity